# Different result from #function and #selector in Swift

Tags: swift, function, comparison, selector

I tried to detect whether a method has been called using `#function` in Swift, but it returns different result than the `#selector`'s description. Here's a working code:

```
class SampleClass {

    var latestMethodCall: Selector?

    @objc func firstMethod() {
        latestMethodCall = #function
    }

    @objc func secondMethod(someParameters: Int, anotherParameter: Int) {
        latestMethodCall = #function
    }

    func isEqualToLatestMethod(anotherMethod anotherMethod: Selector) -> Bool {
        return latestMethodCall?.description == anotherMethod.description
    }
}


let sampleObject = SampleClass()

sampleObject.firstMethod()

let expectedFirstMethod = #selector(SampleClass.firstMethod)

if sampleObject.isEqualToLatestMethod(anotherMethod: expectedFirstMethod) {

    print("Working correctly!")

} else {

    print("Broken selector...")

    if let latestMethodCall = sampleObject.latestMethodCall {
        print("Object's latest method call: \(latestMethodCall.description)") // prints firstMethod()
        print("Expected method call: \(expectedFirstMethod.description)") // prints firstMethod
    }
}

sampleObject.secondMethod(5, anotherParameter: 7)

let expectedSecondMethod = #selector(SampleClass.secondMethod(_:anotherParameter:))

if sampleObject.isEqualToLatestMethod(anotherMethod: expectedSecondMethod) {

    print("Working correctly!")

} else {

    print("Broken selector...")

    if let latestMethodCall = sampleObject.latestMethodCall {
        print("Object's latest method call: \(latestMethodCall.description)") // prints secondMethod(_:anotherParameter:)
        print("Expected method call: \(expectedSecondMethod.description)") // prints secondMethod:anotherParameter:
    }
}
```

From the sample above, I found that `#function` returns Swift-y description, while `#selector` returns ObjC-y description. Is this expected? Or did I done something wrong?

Thank you for taking your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift < 3.0 `Selector` type can be initialized by `String`. Since doing this is unsafe (this approach came from dynamic Objective-C), `#selector` introduced in Swift 2.2. `#selector` will not allow you to define `Selector` for method that not exist.

Now, lets look deeper to initializing `Selector` by string. String for selector should have strictly special signature: for method without arguments `func firstMethod()` it is just method name without braces: `"firstMethod"`. On other hand, `#function` keyword made absolutely not for defining `Selector`'s, and it returns function label with braces:

```
@objc func firstMethod() {
    print(#function)
}
//firstMethod()
```

If you will define method with arguments, you will see that `#function` now will return same but without braces

```
@objc func firstMethod(param: Int) {
    print(#function)
}
//firstMethod
```

since `Selector`, again, expect other signature for it: `"firstMethod:"`.

Conclusion: for defining `Selector` use `#selector`; in Swift >= 3.0 you will have no choice anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see... I forgot to add that I used Swift 2.2 for that. According to your conclusion, I should assigned `latestMethodCall` with `#selector(SampleClass.firstMethod)` for the `firstMethod` and `#selector(SampleClass.secondMethod(_:anotherParameter:))` for the `secondMethod`, right?

Comment: Just tried changing `#function` to the `#selector`, and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!